# JSon report selenium webdriver in node js

Tags: json, node.js, selenium-webdriver

Does anyone know how I can get the report in Json format from selenium webdriver in node Js, any document or sample of code, please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Selenium Webdriver (guess you use http://webdriver.io/ for nodejs) itself does not creates any report, so it needs testing framework like Cucumber.js or NodeUnit that will report.

Actually the answer to your question depends on which testing framework will you choose. You can look at that frameworks in the bottom of the page linked above.